# on your phone or in your phone?

Tags: prepositions

> Don't to do mindless things **on** your phone.
> or
> Don't to do mindless things **in** your phone.

Which one is correct? I feel like either one is weird, "on" implying doing things physically on the surface of a phone, which would only makes sense in "talking with a client on the phone by placing a ear on the exterior of a phone, and "in" physically in the phone.

Comment: When we make an imperative statement, we just use the bare infinitive, not the *to*-infinitive.  So it should be "Don't do", not "Don't **to** do".

Comment: If you have a very, very, very big phone that you can climb into, then it could be “in your phone”.

Answer (score 3):

I would never say "**in** your phone" except when talking about something stored there, like an image file, and even then I would probably say "stored **on** your phone."

The common usage when doing any activity related to a smartphone is to say "**on** your phone," which probably comes from the usage of actual wall-mounted telephones when people would say someone was talking **on** the phone.

Comment: I mostly agree, but I have lots of contacts stored **in** my phone, for example. There's also a battery and lots of electronics and sensors **in** my phone. But definitely I "surf" or play games or whatever **on** my phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you said *in your phone*, that would mean you were doing things *inside* your phone, as you said. *On your phone* is the usual phrase, at least in American English.